# Laravel Date Mutator With Joins

Tags: laravel, date, join, eloquent, format

I've got a mutator setup for the "date" field inside my Schedules table. Everything works fine when I get data directly from it using it's model.

But how would I go about changing the "date" field when I join the Schedules table to another table in a query?

Example: I'm running a query to my GameRequests table and joining the Schedules table to it but the date field isn't being mutated. It's still in a "YYYY-MM-DD" format.

My Mutator inside Schedule Model:

```
/**
 * Always format date to Month / Day / Year when retrieving.
 */
public function getDateAttribute($value) {
    return date('M d, Y', strtotime($value));
}
```

The following works perfect:

```
$list = Schedule::where('team_id', $id)->orderBy('date')->get();

return $list->toJson();
```

The following does not because I'm not calling the Schedule Model:

```
$list = GameRequest::whereIn('team_to', $user_teams)
        ->join('teams as team_to', 'game_requests.team_to', '=', 'team_to.id')
        ->join('teams as team_from', 'game_requests.team_from', '=', 'team_from.id')
        ->join('schedules', 'game_requests.schedule_id', '=', 'schedules.id')
        ->select(
            'game_requests.id as gr_id',
            'game_requests.team_to',
            'game_requests.team_from',
            'team_to.display_name as to_name',
            'team_from.display_name as from_name',
            'schedules.date'
        )
        ->orderBy('date')
        ->get();

    return $list->toJson();
```

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: Just updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL `DATE_FORMAT` function with `selectRaw` to get the date in your desired format.

```
$list = GameRequest::whereIn('team_to', $user_teams)
    ->join('teams as team_to', 'game_requests.team_to', '=', 'team_to.id')
    ->join('teams as team_from', 'game_requests.team_from', '=', 'team_from.id')
    ->join('schedules', 'game_requests.schedule_id', '=', 'schedules.id')
    ->selectRaw(
        'game_requests.id as gr_id',
        'game_requests.team_to',
        'game_requests.team_from',
        'team_to.display_name as to_name',
        'team_from.display_name as from_name',
        'DATE_FORMAT(schedules.date,'%b %d, %Y') as date'
    )
    ->orderBy('date')
    ->get();

return $list->toJson();
```